# Django Rest Framework CORS blocking XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, cors, axios

I have set up my CORS policy using Django-cors-headers with the following settings:

```
APPEND_SLASH=False
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8000',
    'localhost:3000',
    'localhost'
)
```

I have also added it to installed_apps and middleware.

Now I am making a React app for the front end and using AXIOS for my API requests. When I make an API request to log in to my app the CORS policy allows it. But, if I make an API request that requires a Token, I get:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/api/TestConnection/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

It seems that I need to allow XMLHttpRequest for supported protocol schemes but I cannot find anything in the pypi documentation about this.

EDIT:
Here is the AXIOS Request:

```
axios.post("localhost:8000/api/TestConnection/",
    {headers:
      {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('JWTAccess')
      }
    },
    { 
      testString: 'Hello API'
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work with CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! The solution was very simple(of course),

For the request I needed to use part of @HenryM 's solution.

First I needed to establish the default url:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
```

Then I save the payload and header to const variables:

```
const header = {
  headers:{
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('JWTAccess')
  }
}
const payload = {
  testValue: "Hello API"
}
```

Finally, the main issue was that my parameters were in the wrong order:

```
axios.post("TestConnection/", payload, header)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
```

Apparently the propper order, at least when using Django Rest Framework, is payload then header!!!

Thank you to everyone who tired to help!
This was the article that ended up helping me: https://www.techiediaries.com/django-vuejs-api-views/

Answer (score 0):

I Have had a similar issue with a `ReactNative` app which was happening due to ReactNative using IP `10.0.2.2` for localhost (I do not remember the details or why).  I solved it by adding to my class.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/';
    axios.defaults.timeout = 1500;
  }
```

I do not know if this is the right IP but may be worth looking at.

**EDIT**

```
handleRequest() {
    const payload = { username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password } 
    axios
      .post('login/', payload)
      .then(response => {
        const { token, user } = response.data;

        // We set the returned token as the default authorization header
        axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Token ${token}`;

        // Navigate to the home screen
        Actions.main();
      })
      .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
      });
}
```

By saving the Token within my headers it is always sent.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I just tried this, it seems to break my login function and causes it to require me to hit login twice? Then once I have my token, I get a 401, unauthorized. Thoughts?

Comment: This edit is causing the following error:

code 400, message Bad request syntax ('{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer \\"TOKEN\\""}}OPTIONS /api/TestConnection/ HTTP/1.1')

Where token is the JWT Token

Answer (score 0):

The error says "from origin 'http://localhost:3000'" and to "check the cors policy"

I see your CORS policy is

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8000',
    'localhost:3000',
    'localhost'
)
```

maybe try providing the full http url. so

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8000',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'localhost'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, unfortunately it just changed the error to blocking http://localhost:3000

Comment: get rid of the whitelist for now and see if that works. its a bit contradicting to have allow all on in addition to whitelist

Comment: Unfortunately,  this had no effect either.