# Axios blocked by CORS policy with Django REST Framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to make requests to my API(Django REST Framework) using Axios but I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://trvl.hopto.org:8000/api/airports/MSP/routes' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Even tough when you use cUrl to check:

```
curl -I -X GET   -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000"   -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'   http://trvl.hopto.org:8000/api/airports/MSP/routes 2>&1 | grep 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
Response: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Full response from cUrl Options:
OPTIONS request: curl -I -X OPTIONS   -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000"   -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'   http://trvl.hopto.org:8000/api/airports/MSP/routes
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 10:58:01 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

When using Axios:

```
let url = 'http://A.hopto.org:8000/api/airports/MSP/routes';

axios.get(url)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .then((response, ) => {
        console.log(response);
      });


Response:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://API.hopto.org:8000/api/airports/MSP/routes' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The problem is the API has the CORS enabled but I cannot make it work with Axios and React in my WebApp.

UPDATE:

```
Here is my Django settings.py I'm using the https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers module.

**settings.py**

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'trvl',
    'rest_framework',
    'coreapi',
    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure django has your request URL in the allowed origins?

Comment: Double check: Is the response header set for a GET? The Curl response is for an OPTIONS request

Comment: Is the origin page https or http? Your code works fine from an HTTP page, but fails from HTTPS

Comment: I'm using the * wild card to allow all origins and the GET also return the Allow-Origins * header, the origin page is also HTTP

Comment: I found an answer that worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108410/django-rest-framework-cors-blocking-xmlhttprequest?rq=1

Answer (score 13):

This is because you forgot '/' at the end of your url.

```
let url = 'http://A.hopto.org:8000/api/airports/MSP/routes/';
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation on why this work? im really curious

Answer (score 0):

On your back end code you need to add add `http://localhost:3000` as part of the response header for the field `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Also make sure your response has this field `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` include `GET`

You mention that your backend API code has CORS enabled.  If the above doesn't work can  you update your post to include how you have it set up?

Comment: I'm using the wild card * to allow all origins and I'll try adding the GET to allow methods, I just updated the post with my Django settings.py and added the entire OPTIONS response from the cURL

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the `http://` prefix to my `localhost:8000` url